# How to make text appear in X3D & Python?

Tags: python, x3d

I'm trying to make a standard text appear in the scene when the left mousebutton is pressed. However, I am having trouble with routing. This is my X3D code so far:

```
<X3D>
    <Scene>
        <Viewpoint DEF="VP" position="0 0 .6"/>
        <PythonScript DEF="PS" url="test.py"/>

        <Shape>
            <Text DEF="TXT" string="initial message">
                <FontStyle justify='MIDDLE' size='0.02' />
            </Text>
        </Shape>

        <MouseSensor DEF="MS"/>

        <ROUTE fromNode="MS" fromField="leftButton" toNode="PS" toField="showText"/>
        <ROUTE fromNode="PS" fromField="showText" toNode="TXT" toField="string"/>
    </Scene>
</X3D>
```

And the Python code:

```
from H3DInterface import *

class ShowText(TypedField(MFString, SFBool)):

    def __init__(self):
        MFString.__init__(self)
        self.inactive_txt = 'Press left mousebutton'
        self.active_txt = 'Hello World!'

    def update(self, event):
        if event.getValue() == 1:
            return self.active_txt
        else:
            return self.inactive_txt


showText = ShowText()
```

This is the warning I got, but could not resolve:

> Warning: invalid return value from update()-function for Python defined field of type PythonScript_000000000722E320.ShowText

Which is strange to me, since the text-node has the attribute string, which is of base_type MFString.

Answer (score 0):

The MFString must be fed by defining the string as:

```
self.active_txt = ['some string']
```